# How to force Windows Mobile device to use GPRS for internet connection

Tags: c++, windows, mobile

I'm on WiFi and EDGE/GPRS too. I'm using WiFi for debugging in Visual Studio 2008 but I want my app use EDGE/GPRS for internet connection (socket creation) not WiFi

thx & bye,
Attila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
I deploy my app on device, I turn off wifi, I start my app, It uses GPRS, finally I turn on wifi and attach debugger to my device